# BigCommerce product object/id from front end javascript

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I am trying to add content to a BigCommerce product page via the Script Manager.

Is there a way to get the current product object/id from front end JS?

There's lots of documentation if working in the Stencil framework, but is this possible from straight front end JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Using `Stencil` you can inject objects in Javascript like this:

   ```
   {{inject "myProductName" product.title}}

   <script>
   // Note the lack of quotes around the jsContext handlebars helper, it becomes a string automatically.
   var jsContext = JSON.parse({{jsContext}});

   /* jsContext would output "{\"myProductName\": \"Sample Product\"}" which can feed directly into
   your JavaScript. */

   console.log(jsContext.myProductName); // Will output: Sample Product
   </script>
   ```
2. Using JS only is not as elegant. You could look for the add to cart form, and then look for the hidden input with the name `product_id`, which has the products' id as the value.

   ```
   const addToCartForm = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('form')).find(item => item.action.value === 'add' && item.action.name === 'action');

   if (typeof addToCartForm === 'object' && addToCartForm.hasOwnProperty('product_id')) {
           return addToCartForm.product_id.value;
   }
   ```
3. There is yet another option: `BCData`. Every product page has a variable named `BCData`, which has data that looks like this:

   ```
   {"csrf_token":"TOKEN_HERE","product_attributes":{"purchasable":true,"purchasing_message":"MY MESSAGE","sku":"MY SKU","upc":"MY UPC","stock":0,"instock":true,"stock_message":"MY STOCK MESSAGE","weight":0.35,"base":true,"image":"https://www.test.com/my-image","price":{"without_tax":{"formatted":"$35.00","value":35,"currency":"USD"},"tax_label":"Tax"}}}
   ```

   You could grab the `sku`, if all your products have skus, and then base your JS functions off of this instead of the `id`. I know that you specifically asked for a solution based off of `id`, but I wanted you to know that there is a JS object that Bigcommerce loads natively. Sadly, at the time of this comment, the `BCData` does not include the products' id.

Good luck!

[Documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#injection-helpers) for point #1.